# Intergrating GPS in to a C# Application

Tags: c#, android, iphone, windows, gps

What's the programing library that I can use to integrate GPS functionality into my desktop app?

- The library i need should be able to support Android, iphone and Windows, mobile phone clients.
- It needs to fully support C#.
- The server is on a Windows OS

What this system intended to do is, track the service people in a company using GPS, and send that data to company's clients'-- whom have installed the server, so they can track the nearest service person to their location.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is using Xamarin, you get cross platform libraries for all your needed platforms in C# and supports gps usage on all.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful.